# How can I customise a picker to save option to DB in .NET MAUI using SQLite?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, maui

I want to utilise a picker in my .NET MAUI project for the admin to select a client for my storybook illustrator company. I don't know how to databind the options of the picker like I would a entry to the Database.

This is my Picker with the options

```
 <Picker Title="Select a Client">
                                          <Picker.Items>
                                            <x:String>Penny's Creations</x:String>
                                            <x:String>Bargain Books</x:String>
                                            <x:String>Easy Reads</x:String>
                                            <x:String>Penguin Classics</x:String>
                                           
                                          </Picker.Items>
                                        </Picker>
```

And this is my working entry connecting to the DB

```
<Entry Text="{Binding ActiveProject.Client}" Placeholder="Penny's Creations" PlaceholderColor="Grey" FontSize="18" FontFamily="PoppinsRegular" TextColor="#102D4C"></Entry>
```

How do I utilise the functionality of the entry (with databinding) with my picker options?

My Database Code

```
public partial class AddUpdateStaffViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        //test
        public ObservableCollection<StaffModel> Staffs { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<StaffModel>();

        [ObservableProperty]
        private StaffModel _staffDetail = new StaffModel();

        private readonly IStaffService _staffService;
        public AddUpdateStaffViewModel(IStaffService staffService)
        {
            _staffService = staffService;
        }
[RelayCommand]
        public async void GetStaffList()
        {
            Staffs.Clear();
            var staffList = await _staffService.GetStaffList();
            if (staffList?.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var staff in staffList)
                {
                    Staffs.Add(staff);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What does the Entry have to do with saving to the db?  Where is your database code?

Comment: Have added my database code

Comment: the code you posted appears to be your VM, not DB code.  And I still have no idea what specifically you need help with.  Do you just want to bind your Picker to a list of DB values instead of hardcoding it?